# [Perforce]p4 files command parse arguments wrong when there are unicodes in arguments

Tags: unicode, perforce

You can just try

> p4 files //Root//哈哈.txt

The supposed result is

> //Root//哈哈.txt - no such file(s).

Instead, you will see

> Usage: files [-a -A -e -m max] [-U] files...
>       Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Apparently, p4 files command could not parse the unicode argument "//Root//哈哈.txt" and discard it.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell might not support the character set you're trying to use.  Note that the p4 command line client lets you set a separate charset to decode command line args, to let you work around this:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4COMMANDCHARSET.html

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work. The connection encode is utf8 and I tried it in the command line tool of p4v which is provided by Perforce and also in a Windows cmd.

Comment: Are you sure that you're entering your command line arg in utf8 and are you sure it's not the shell that's eating it?  What if you run "`echo //Root//哈哈.txt`"?